# Does document reload every time DOM changes via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I kind of have a newbie question. I've done some testing, but I didn't get anything solid, so does the whole document reload when DOM is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the document is not reloaded when the DOM is updated.

You can test it using this example: http://jsfiddle.net/AATC6/

There is an alert in the load event for the page, and you can click on the link to add an element to the DOM, which does not cause the load event to be triggered.

Comment: Ah, I was primarily asking because of /that. I noticed that the onLoad event doesn't fire, but somewhere I read that adding elements like this:

add "element", add "element", add "element", add "element" is slow and expensive, and should be done as add "element element element element." (I'm having trouble expressing myself today, sorry) So, I was wondering why's that... Now, this might be time to ask a new question, actually. LOL

Comment: @with a dot.: That depends on how you add elements. If you use `.innerHTML+='...'` to add elements, that is slow because it will recreate all elements in the container each time, not just add elements at the end.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not. However there is an event for some browsers `DOMSubtreeModified` which can be used to track changes to the DOM.